# RegEx | Detecting numbers < 10 in string (date representation)

Tags: javascript, regex, date

I am using JavaScript to render a date in the client culture.

```
(new Date("2020-01-01")).toLocaleDateString()
```

which, in my case, returns

```
"1.1.2020"
```

(but also could return 1/1/2020 or whatever culture the client has)

The numbers have to have at least two digits (=> 01.01.2020).

With the following I tried to identify the numbers with only one digit, but it didn't work properly in my test cases:

```
[^\d]([\d])[^\d]
```

Test cases:

```
1.2.2020
22.1.2000
1-2-2020
1311/29/9
2000/1/1
22/1/2000
```

Does anyone know how to fix this problem without splitting it into their three parts and checking each part in JavaScript?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Beside non-numbers (`[^\d]`) you'll also have to check for start and end of string (`^` and `$`), something like `(^|[^\d])([\d])([^\d]|$)` or simpler `(^|\D)([\d])(\D|$)`

Comment: 2020-01-01 will be parsed as UTC, so for users west of Greenwich *toLocaleDateString* will produce a date for 2019-12-31. *toLocaleDateString* will produce different format strings depending on the host "locale" settings, or not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
(new Date("2020-01-01")).toLocaleDateString("de-DE",{
  day:"2-digit",
  month:"2-digit",
  year:"numeric"
})
```

You can view more options [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34015511/12547475).

Comment: That did the trick, thank you very much! :)